# Create new class from data.frame in R

Tags: r

I am toying around with functions, classes and methods in R.
To have a "hand on" exercise that could also be useful, I have decided to create my "package" for taking care of my household budget.
Simply put, I want a series of functions, classes and methods to calculate stuff, plot different kind of charts and what not.
The first thing that I wanted to do is creating a "Budget" class: this should take in a csv with certain columns and return an object "Budget" that inherit the same method of a data frame but to whom I can apply a set of "Budgets" methods.
Here is my take

```
prepareData = function (csv, type=1) {

if (type == 1) {
Data = read.csv(csv,dec = ".")}
else if (type == 2) {
Data = read.csv2(csv,dec = ",")}
else {stop ("Accetable value for type are 1 and 2")}

NamesToHave = c("Date","Title","Amount","Category")

if (sum(as.numeric(colnames(Data) %in% NamesToHave)) < 4) {
    stop ("The csv file has not the mandatory columns (Data, Title, Amount, Category)")}




if (class(try(tolower(Data$Title),silent = T)) == "try-error" | class(try(tolower(Data$Category),silent = T)) == "try-error") {
    stop("Are you sure there are no special character in your csv file ?")} 

Data$Day = sapply(strsplit(as.character(Data$Date), "/"),"[[",1)
Data$Month = month.abb[as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(as.character(Data$Date), "/"),"[[",2))]
Data$Year = sapply(strsplit(as.character(Data$Date), "/"),"[[",3)

Data = Data[with(Data, order(Year, Month, Day)), ]
Data$Amount = as.character(Data$Amount)
Data$Amount = as.numeric(as.character(Data$Amount))

class(Data) <- append(class(Data),"Budget")
return(Data)
}
```

Now, this return a data frame with all the necessary modifications, and overall it works fine as a function, but if I take a csv as follows

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(22L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("01/10/2016", 
"01/11/2016", "02/10/2016", "04/10/2016", "04/11/2016", "05/10/2016", 
"05/11/2016", "06/10/2016", "06/11/2016", "07/10/2016", "08/10/2016", 
"08/11/2016", "09/10/2016", "09/11/2016", "10/10/2016", "10/11/2016", 
"11/10/2016", "12/11/2016", "14/10/2016", "16/10/2016", "18/10/2016", 
"20/09/2016", "20/10/2016", "21/10/2016", "22/09/2016", "22/10/2016", 
"23/09/2016", "23/10/2016", "25/09/2016", "25/10/2016", "26/09/2016", 
"26/10/2016", "27/10/2016", "28/10/2016", "29/10/2016", "30/10/2016"
), class = "factor"), Title = structure(c(20L, 6L, 36L, 29L, 
30L, 11L), .Label = c("Bagpiper", "beer debaser", "Br", "brewdog", 
"Burger King", "Clas", "coop", "Coop", "Eriksdalbadet", "etc", 
"ETC", "Flippin", "Fotografiska", "Gateau Agneta", "Grekisk fastfood", 
"Grill", "Gunnarson", "Gunnarsson", "hemkop", "HK", "Hotorhallen", 
"ICA", "ICA Skinnskat", "Igor Sport", "Intersport", "Kak", "klattercentret", 
"LullesFagel", "Mae Thai", "MamaWolf", "Material", "Matrerial", 
"Oriental Supermarket", "Paradiset", "Pendeltag Uppsala", "PGW", 
"Pressbyran", "Primeburger", "Primo Ciao ciao", "R Asia", "Systembolaget", 
"taxi Skinnskat", "The Cure drinks", "Udden pensionat", "Ugglan", 
"Wentzels hobby"), class = "factor"), Amount = c(167.27, 331, 
971, 99, 192, 3289), Category = structure(c(10L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
6L, 3L), .Label = c("Drink", "extra", "Extra", "Extra_Fede", 
"extra_food", "Extra_food", "extra_laure", "Extra_Laure", "food", 
"Food"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", "Title", "Amount", 
"Category"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I run

```
Data = prepareData("name.csv")
class(Data)
```

The output is just "data.frame". But if I then run again from terminal the second to last line of the function

```
class(Data) <- append(class(Data),"Budget")
class(Data)
```

I got "data.frame" and "Budget" as output.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, because there are several problems with the exemple you posted. Please, take a look at [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue either, The object appears to have both the correct classes.

Comment: I know, strangely enough, when I have fixed one unrelated problem (see the answer below) the problem get fixed. As Tomas says, it could be helpful sometimes to restart R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was here:

```
if (as.numeric(colnames(Data) %in% NamesToHave) != 4) {}
```

The first comparation will be vectorized performed and return `TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE`, which will become `1 1 1 1` when gone throw `as.numeric()`. Then, this vector will be compared to `!= 4`, which is vectorized performed and return `TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE` (all the 'one's are different from four). The if()` statement will not evaluet the whole vector, just it's first element (and throw you a warning message).

To solve this issue, you just have to switch the `as.numeric()` function to `sum()`.

```
if (sum(colnames(Data) %in% NamesToHave) != 4) {}
```

When you sum a logical vector, `R`will coerce it to numerical: all `TRUE` become `1` and all `FASLE` become `0`. Now you will have the 4 sum that will evaluet `FALSE`in the if statement, and the function it run smoothly. Once I solved it, it has both classes when I first run it.

As said in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it good to restart `R` before posting your question and make sure you're still having the problem you're reporting.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I found out the same thing while I was correcting my example.
However, as a follow up and a way to improve myself: what was lacking in your opinion for making this a minimal reproducible example ?
I put in the data and the code, what could have I done better ?
In any case, thanks again!

Comment: We did not need to know every case you dealt with before the function itself (all those if-elses in the beginning). In fact, if you had taken them off before posting the question, you would realize that the problem was not in assigning classes, but in handling possible errors.

Comment: Ok, got it.
Thank you for the feedback!